# How to plot dates from a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I am new to python and I am having some issues to plot my dates from a csv file.
The code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r"file.csv",index_col=0)

print(df.describe())

BHSI_cycle, BHSI_trend = sm.tsa.filters.hpfilter(df['BHSI-TCA'])
df['BHSI_trend'] = BHSI_trend
df['BHSI_cycle'] = BHSI_cycle

BHSI_plot = df[['BHSI-TCA','BHSI_trend']].plot(figsize=(12,10))
plt.show(BHSI_plot)

BHSI_plot2 = df[['BHSI_cycle']].plot(figsize=(12,10))
plt.show(BHSI_plot2)
```

And the CSV file is:

```
Date    BHSI-TCA
23/05/2006  14821
25/05/2006  14878
30/05/2006  14837
```

How can I plot the dates?

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing dates properly when you import from csv.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"file.csv", index_col=0, parse_dates=<your_date_column>)
```